# Getting a base64 png from a PDF.JS pdf converted to a canvas tag?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas, pdf.js

I'm trying to get a base64 encoded png value from a canvas that was created by converting a pdf with the PDF.JS library by Mozilla.

So I had a base64 encoded PDF that I converted into a HTML canvas. I now need to convert that HTML canvas into a base64 encoded png value that I can use with a HTML img tag that displays properly.

I tried the HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL(), however it doesn't display anything. I tried using the same method with some green boxes drawn in canvas and it worked fine, meaning that the base64 encoded pdf converted to canvas just doesn't want to work with that method.

Any other solutions or a workaround for the solution I tried?

**I need to do this inside my JS code with my HTML.

```
function convertDataURIToBinary() {
      var raw = window.atob(BASE64 OF PDF);
      var rawLength = raw.length;
      var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

      for(var i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
        array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return array;
    }
    var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary();

    PDFJS.workerSrc = "http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js";
    var canvas = _el.querySelector(".insertHere");
    PDFJS.getDocument(pdfAsArray).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
      pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
        var scale = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);


        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
        canvas = _el.querySelector(".insertHere");
        var imgSrc = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imgSrc;
        _el.querySelector(".insertImageLabel").appendChild(img);

      });
    });
```

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but you could take a screenshot of the canvas.

Comment: @UltrasoundJelly Thanks for the suggestion, however I need it done inside my code. I should've clarified that.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code to work with?

Comment: `"I had a base64 encoded PDF that I converted into a HTML canvas"` - And just how did you do this? You can't just use setImageData with a base64 encoded PDF, anymore than you can throw a base64 encoded mp3 at a canvas and expect a visualization of it...

Comment: @enhzflep, `setImageData` doesn't exist in neither Canvas2d API nor in pdf.js library, I guess you're referring to `putImageData` which only works with `ImageData` objects and OP never mentioned any of it anywhere in his post. However, he said he uses [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) library, which has a [`render()`](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/#rendering-the-page) method expecting a canvas context. However, we do lack information about where the pdf and its content come from to be able to help OP.

Comment: @Kaiido - yeah, I know. I am, correct - the OP did not. My guessing wasn't helpful to the question and by my estimates, neither is yours. The last sentence of both your most recent comment and the one deleted seems to have been the most useful thing intimated thus far...

Comment: toDataURL() shall work just fine -- I bet OP does not wait until render() finish its async completion.

Comment: @async5 As I said in my OP. I tested it with a green box written in canvas and it worked for me fine. The data is coming through with the pdf data canvas, but it's just broken, shows nothing.

Comment: There is no source code provided, so it's hard to assume anything. Do you wait on promise returned by render()? If not, toDataURL() will return an empty image.

Comment: @async5 Where did I go wrong? I've added my code above in the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not waiting on the promise returned by render() to finish async operation. See https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/learning/prevnext.html#L76 how to wait on completion:

```
  ...
  var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
  // Wait for rendering to finish
  renderTask.promise.then(function () {
    // Page rendered, now take snapshot.
  });
  ...
```

Comment: Hurray! Thanks a lot for your help, very much appreciated! This was of course, exactly my problem. I'm unfamiliar with promises and use callback functions myself and wasn't clear on how to do that or that it needed done.